# react-native-pager-view is not working with FlaLlist in react Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-pager-view

```
<FlatListdata={listViewData}
style={styles.innerBack}horizontal={false}
showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
renderItem={({item}) => (
<TouchableOpacitystyle={styles.clickButton}// onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Vaction', {item})}
activeOpacity={0.8} // Adjust opacity as needed\>
<View style={styles.sliderContainer}>
<PagerView style={styles.pagerView} initialPage={0} scrollEnabled={true}>{item?.property_image?.map((image, index) => (
<View key={index}>
<StyledViewsource={{uri: https://admin.podsliving.com/storage/${image.image},}}style={styles.image}/></View>))}
</PagerView>
<View style={styles.paginationContainer}>{item?.property_image?.map((_, index) => (<Viewkey={index}style={[styles.paginationDot,index === currentPage && styles.activeDot,]}/>))}</View></View><Text style={styles.propertyTitle}>{item.pro_title}</Text><Text style={styles.propertyDesc}>{item.property_category.cat_name} {item.city}</Text><View style={styles.amountRow}><View><Text style={styles.amountText}>${item?.property_attribute?.base_price_per_night}<Text style={styles.dayText}>/night</Text></Text></View><View style={styles.amountRows}><Imagestyle={styles.startImage}source={require('../../../assets/star.png')}/><Text style={styles.ratingText}>4.5</Text></View></View></TouchableOpacity>)}keyExtractor={item => item.user_id}/>
```

Everything this fine, but when I slide left to right so it's not working. currently version is "react-native-pager-view": "^6.2.0".